# How to create index on type object?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Currently i'm working with type object in oracle 11g. In this i have DB objects as follows:

1. table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE students
     (rollno NUMBER(15) primary key, s_Name VARCHAR2(20), Marks type_1
     );
   ```
2. Type object specification is

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE type type_1
   AS
     object
     (
       sub_1 NUMBER,
       sub_2 NUMBER,
       sub_3 NUMBER,
       member FUNCTION total
       RETURN NUMBER,
       member FUNCTION e_result
       RETURN VARCHAR2);
   ```
3. It's body

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE type body type_1
   AS
     member FUNCTION total
     RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
     RETURN (sub_1+sub_2+sub_3);
   END;
   member FUNCTION e_result
     RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
     DECLARE
       temp NUMBER;
     BEGIN
       temp  :=sub_1+sub_2+sub_3;
       IF(temp>50) THEN
         RETURN ('pass');
       ELSE
         RETURN ('fail');
       END IF;
     END;
   END;
   ```

After create all these thing even I've successfully populated the student table using

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..800 LOOP
        FOR j IN 1..400 LOOP
INSERT INTO students
VALUES     (sequence1.NEXTVAL,
            dbms_random.String('A', 5),
            Type_1(Round(dbms_random.Value(10, 100)), Round(
            dbms_random.Value(10, 100)), Round(dbms_random.Value(10, 100))));
END LOOP;
END LOOP;

dbms_output.Put_line('completed');

COMMIT;
END;

/
```

I need to create bitmap index on `e_result` column and normal index on `tot` column.

I have tried

```
create index id1 on students(marks.total)
```

and

```
create bitmap index bid1 on students(marks.e-result)
```

But I can't. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: just curious why you'd create a nested table of objects rather than simply creating a MARKS table and joining to STUDENTS as needed?  But maybe this is just an exercise in pl/sql?

Comment: @ tbone:ya ya exactly...this is just practices with type objects dude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you have to have your functions declared as `DETERMINISTIC` for them to be used in an SQL index (i.e. you have to assert to Oracle that given the same input, they give the same output).

eg:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE type type_1
  2  AS
  3    object
  4    (
  5      sub_1 NUMBER,
  6      sub_2 NUMBER,
  7      sub_3 NUMBER,
  8      member FUNCTION total
  9      RETURN NUMBER deterministic,
 10      member FUNCTION e_result
 11      RETURN VARCHAR2 deterministic
 12  );
 13  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE type body type_1
  2  AS
  3    member FUNCTION total
  4    RETURN NUMBER deterministic
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7    RETURN (sub_1+sub_2+sub_3);
  8  END;
  9  member FUNCTION e_result
 10    RETURN VARCHAR2 deterministic
 11  IS
 12      temp NUMBER;
 13    BEGIN
 14      temp  :=sub_1+sub_2+sub_3;
 15      IF(temp>50) THEN
 16        RETURN ('pass');
 17      ELSE
 18        RETURN ('fail');
 19      END IF;
 20    END;
 21  END;
 22  /
```

secondly you have to use `()` when calling the function otherwise it will assume it a column named `total`:

```
SQL> create index id1 on students (marks.total());

Index created.

SQL> create bitmap index bid1 on students(marks.e_result());

Index created.
```

then you should see the indexes used:

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'STUDENTS', method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size skewonly')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> explain plan for select * from students s where s.marks.e_result() = 'fail';

Explained.

SQL> @explain ""

Plan hash value: 1595221732

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          |   635 | 17780 |   109   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | STUDENTS |   635 | 17780 |   109   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   2 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS|          |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE | BID1     |       |       |            |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: :is it like function based index?

Comment: @ThiyaguATR They are function indexes (as they are created on object Functions).